# Pass unapplied case class to function

Tags: scala, function, tuples, case-class

I have a case class with two fields and a function which accepts the same arguments. Is where a way to pass contents of case class to this function without explicitly specifying all fields or ugly unapplying?

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
val user = User("Peter", 23)

def func(name: String, age: Int) = {...}

func(user.name, user.age) //works
Function.tupled(func(_,_))(User.unapply(user).get) //works, but ugly
// func(_,_) is explicit because it can be a method of a class
```

Comment: `(func _).tupled(User.unapply(user).get)` works and is a little shorter

Answer (score 2):

The simplest vanilla Scala solution is the one Tom suggested in the comments:

```
(func _).tupled(User.unapply(user).get)
```

If happen to have Shapeless in scope (maybe it's already a dependency), you could also use it to convert `user` to a tuple:

```
import shapeless._

val gen = Generic[User]
(func _).tupled(gen.to(user).tupled)
```